# Why do bicycle tires tend to sync?

Tags: everyday-life

There are alot of bicycles in my university, I've noticed that most (80%) of the tyres move in sync. As you can tell by the reflectors in the attached picture. I thought it was just a coincidence.

So I conducted a little experiment, I manually rotated my tires 90 degrees out of phase with each other and after a little riding they would sync up again.

I could not figure out why this happens.

[image]

Comment: When you performed your experiment, what did you do next after "rotated my tires 90 degrees?" How did you decide when to stop doing it? How many times did you repeat the experiment? What were your criteria for "in sync again?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow After I rotated my tires 90 degrees I rode my bicycle. Then after a few km of riding they would be in sync in the sense that they are oriented the same. As you can tell by the reflectors in the above picture. I did this 3-4 times

Comment: @Linkin What happened after they were in sync? When you ride them again, do they remain synced up, or do they go out of sync after a while?

Comment: @AlphaLife They stay in sync.

Answer (score 0):

If the tires are very nearly the same size, they will stay in sync for a while if they get in sync.

If the tires are not exactly the same size, they will stay in sync for a while and then get out of sync. A while later, they will be back in sync.

So your observation of your bike makes sense.

If you take pictures of many bicycles, you will probably find that at any instant, there is no preference for being in sync. If you watch for it, you will find that every bike gets in sync at some point.